# If $T(B)=AB$ then prove that tr$(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ for an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been given a question in Linear Algebra, the field is $\mathbb{R}$.

> $A$ is an $n\times n$ is a symmetric matrix s.t. rank$(A)$ = dim(Im$(A)$) = $1$. An operator $T:\mathbb{M}_{n,n}\rightarrow\mathbb{M}_{n,n}$ is defined by: $T(B)=AB$. Proof that tr$(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

I have reached the conclusion that the rank of $T$ is maximum $1$ for any $B\neq 0$ $(\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leq \min{\{\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B)\}})$.

I thought maybe the matrix $(I)$ could be the eigenvector for eigenvalue tr$(A)$, but I really don't know how to start.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical equations in your question. It is very easy to learn and makes things look neat.

Comment: Something is wrong.  For $n=1,$ i.e. real numbers,  if $A=1$ and $B=2,$ we have $BA=2$ and $tr A=1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc T([2]) = [1][2] = 1[2]… it is T(B) = AB not BA

Comment: @CSquared In one dimensional case ($n=1$) we have $AB=BA.$ The eigenvalue of $AB$ is equal $2,$ while $trA=1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc i disagree. we need $T(B) = cB$. taking $A$ and $B$ as you described in your example for the one dimensional case, we see that $(A - c)B=0$. Since $B\neq 0$, then $c=1$. Same reasoning if $T(B) = BA$.

Comment: @CSquared OK. The question deals with eigenvalues of $T$ not $AB.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc that is what i believe i found above: the eigenvalue of $T$ in your specific example.

Comment: "I have reached the conclusion that the rank of  is maximum 1 for any ≠0".  This conclusion is false.  In fact $\text{rank}(T) = n$

Answer (score 1):

As $A$ is one dimensional it can be represented as $Ax=\langle x,v\rangle w$ for nonzero vectors $v$ and $w,$ such that $\|w\|=1.$ Here $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean norm and $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product. Then
$tr A=\langle w,v\rangle.$ For a nonzero vector $u$ let $Bx=\langle x,u\rangle w.$
Then $B\neq 0$ and
$$ABx=\langle Bx,v\rangle w=\langle x,u\rangle\,\langle w,v\rangle w =(tr A)\, Bx$$
Hence $AB=(tr A) B.$

**Remark** Any matrix $B,$ which is an eigenvector of $T$ must of the form described above, as the condition $AB=\lambda B$ implies, that $B$ is one dimensional and the range of $B$ is spanned by $w.$

Answer (score 0):

The symmetry hypothesis appears to be unnecessary.

**Hint** Since $\operatorname{rank} A = 1$, $$A = v w^\top$$ for some nonzero vectors $v, w$; notice that $$\operatorname{tr} A = w^\top v .$$ Substitute the above decomposition to show that $T(A) = (\operatorname{tr} A) A$, that is, that $A$ itself is an eigenvector of $T$ of eigenvalue $\operatorname{tr} A$.

> $$T(A) = A^2 = (v w^\top) (v w^\top) = v (w^\top v) w^\top = v (\operatorname{tr} A) w^\top = (\operatorname{tr} A) v w^\top = (\operatorname{tr} A) A .$$